# How to sort an array after it's been translated?

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization

I have a dropdown with a list of countries coming from the back-end. I translate them using i18n localisation. They arrive alphabetically ordered in English and the dropdown correctly shows the list of English countries.

When I run the platform in other languages, they are translated correctly, but the problem is that they keep the English sorting.

Is there a way to sort the list of countries alphabetically after the i18n translation is applied?

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you translate them in the html via a pipe for instance or in the ts file?

Comment: I have a CountriesEnumI18nComponent that I call in the html file like this: <dm-lib-countries-enum-i18n [key]="item.id"></dm-lib-countries-enum-i18n> --- then I handle the translation in that component's template with a list of countries like this: <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'AD'" i18n="Country@@AD">Andorra</ng-container>

Answer (score 1):

You can use sort pipe :

```
export class SortPipe implements PipeTransform {

transform(value: any[], sortOrder: SortOrder | string = 'asc', sortKey?: string): any {
    sortOrder = sortOrder && (sortOrder.toLowerCase() as any);

    if (!value || (sortOrder !== 'asc' && sortOrder !== 'desc')) return value;

    let numberArray = [];
    let stringArray = [];

    if (!sortKey) {
      numberArray = value.filter(item => typeof item === 'number').sort();
      stringArray = value.filter(item => typeof item === 'string').sort();
    } else {
      numberArray = value.filter(item => typeof item[sortKey] === 'number').sort((a, b) => a[sortKey] - b[sortKey]);
      stringArray = value
        .filter(item => typeof item[sortKey] === 'string')
        .sort((a, b) => {
          if (a[sortKey] < b[sortKey]) return -1;
          else if (a[sortKey] > b[sortKey]) return 1;
          else return 0;
        });
    }
    const sorted = numberArray.concat(stringArray);
    return sortOrder === 'asc' ? sorted : sorted.reverse();
  }
```

}

There is a Stackbliz sample:
[Angular sort pipe Stackblits](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sort-pipe-ivknip?file=src%2Fapp%2Fshared%2Fpipes%2Fsort.pipe.ts)